# I need to create a field with the total value of the invoice in stock using the origin field to pull right

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I want to bring the total value of the invoice to the stock.picking using the origin to bring it right I tried to do something else, it did not work can you help me?

```
from odoo import api, fields, models, _
from odoo.exceptions import UserError

class StockPicking(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'stock.picking'

    def get_x_total(self):
        current_total = self.env['account.invoice'].search([('origin','=',self.origin)])
        x_total = current_total.('account.invoice').amount_total
        return x_total

    x_amout_total = fields.Float('Valor Total', default=lambda self: self.get_x_total())
```

Answer (score 0):

> Guessing you are newbie to odoo.
>   fixed couple of things in your code now it should work :)
>
> 1) you need to compute attribute instead of default for computed fields in odoo v8-v10
>
> 2) Self will come as set of records so iterate over it
>
> 3) in new api we do not return from compute method just assign values to field

## [check this orm api docs for development](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html)

```
from odoo import api, fields, models

class StockPicking(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'stock.picking'

    @api.multi
    @api.depends('origin')
    def get_x_total(self):
        for rec in self:
            invoice_rec = self.env['account.invoice'].search([('origin','=',rec.origin)], limit=1)
            rec.x_amout_total = invoice_rec.amount_total or 0.0  #in case no origin default value

    x_amout_total = fields.Float('Valor Total', compute='get_x_total')
```